# How can I create a job to process all documents in an elasticsearch index as a data stream?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I want to create a job that can run through all documents in an elasticsearch index and apply some task on each.

Our platform is generally built on NodeJS so we could use things such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-streams

Can anyone suggest other ways to achieve the same thing? Maybe some way that is native to the ELK stack?

Answer (score 1):

The way to scan all the documents in an Elasticsearch Index is to use the Scroll API:
[Scroll API docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)

From the elasticsearch-streams package docs you pasted, it looks like they do support scroll, so I would recommend using this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-streams#stream-scrollscan-results-from-elasticsearch